# Xcode Promoting ViewController to TabViewController doesn't work?

Tags: ios, xcode, nstabviewcontroller

A newbie question here.

If you had initially a View Controller on your Storyboard.

Then you wanted to promote this to a Tab View Controller.

Why is it that it doesn't work, if I changed that View Controller's inherit from the identity inspector to TabViewController, it doesn't seem to work.

What I mean is, if I then try to create a segue reference to the TabViewController's viewControllers reference list, it doesn't work, because viewControllers isn't available.

I guess my question is, is there more to it than just changing the base class for that controllers object for it to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would need to see a bit more what you did there, but the matter requires a bit more than, The Tab Bar Controller include an UITabBar component that also needs to be included. The segues to another view from the tabs are also specific for that, like the new views will be integrated under the tab controller.